# SQL DISTINCT not working as it should ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my code behind:

```
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [movie_id], [file_path], [is_poster] FROM [movie_image] WHERE [is_poster] LIKE 0 ORDER BY [movie_id] DESC";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        browse.DataSource = dt;
        browse.DataBind();
```

In my ascx file:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="browse" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
                    <img src="<%# Eval("file_path").ToString() %>" alt="file"/> 
              </td>
              <td>
                   <p><%# Eval("movie_id").ToString() %></p>
              </td>
          </tr>          
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When I run this, it displays all the records from the movie_image that aren't a poster (poster=0) but the movie_id comes out in duplicates when I explicitly said DISTINCT in my sql statement.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: This will compare the movie image records and will return a result if the combination of all three fields is distinct, is this the functionality you want?

Comment: Distinct runs on ALL columns of your Select.   " [movie_id], [file_path], [is_poster] " is distinct...not just the first column.

Answer (score 3):

The DISTINCT applies to *the entire* tuple `(movie_id, file_path, is_poster)` and *not* just the `movie_id` column.

The simplest fix is to probably use

```
"SELECT DISTINCT [movie_id] FROM .."
```

although then *only* the movie ID is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

As @user2864740 said, it's returning distinct tuples.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT [movie_id], [file_path], [is_poster] FROM [movie_image] 
WHERE [is_poster] LIKE 0 
AND [movie_id] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [movie_id] FROM [movie_image])
ORDER BY [movie_id] DESC
```